# SQLite + Object oriented programming

Tags: android, sqlite, oop

Creating android financial manager application with using of SQLite.
My question is how to deal with the database in terms of object oriented programming?
Say I want to write information about a purchase into the database.
Should I:
1) Get user information from EditTexts, put it into an object say "Purchase", which contains fields: productName, ammount, price...
And only than put information from the object into the database?
2) Or put data from EditTexts directly straight into the database?
3) Another way?

Comment: There are many libraries for Android that let you define model classes for your data and which help you read and write that data to an SQLite database. I've recently been using [SquiDB](https://github.com/yahoo/squidb) and think it's great, but a web search will find others for you to try as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used many different frameworks available out there, from SQLite to ORMLite. But, in terms of speed, there is no alternative to [Realm.io](http://realm.io). You can basically create your data models and define them as Realm Objects. Then the rest is easy, you can read, write and query among the data models you created.

If you want to know, what is a better way to use SQLite, than you can check [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting for the future. In this app I want to use SQLite for practice and deeper understanding

Comment: @Albert See my edit to my question than. You will see how the Objects are created from Cursors and how you can use them in your project.

Comment: Thank you, great tutorial. I think it will help me in this case

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. Create objects that does represents your data.

Create your Database Class to use the objects instead of methods with multiple arguments.

Comment: Your answer is extremely incomplete. It's true that application should operate with entities describing domain logic, rather than working with strings and ints, but you'll still have to put those into an SQLite database.

Comment: Well.. he gave options.. i added info anywa

Answer (score 0):

I would make a container class that you use as a way of keeping the code clean.